# What am I receiving undefined when building this string? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables, undefined

I"m attempting to build a string in order to put the results in a DataTables table.

I'm taking an array and using regex to get everything in it's own index and my resultant string array is this:

```
["41.8059016", "-77.0727825", "School Zone",
 "41.804526", "-77.075572", "Something",
 "41.804398", "-77.0743704", "Some Other Thing",
 "41.8073731", "-77.07304", "Pedestrian"]
```

One big string array with everything in its own index. Next I'm using a loop and building a string in order to pass it to a datatables table.  The result of which SHOULD look like this:

```
var dataString = [
    ["41.8059016", "-77.0727825", "School Zone"],
    ["41.804526", "-77.075572", "Something"],
    ["41.804398", "-77.0743704", "Some Other Thing"],
    ["41.8073731", "-77.07304", "Pedestrian"]
    ];
```

Instead I'm getting this:

```
var dataString = undefined["41.8059016", "-77.0727825", "School Zone"],
                 ["41.804526", "-77.075572", "Something"],
                 ["41.804398", "-77.0743704", "Some Other Thing"],
                 ["41.8073731", "-77.07304", "Pedestrian"]
                 ];
```

Here is my loop code to build the string from the array:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < routePoints.length-3; i+=3){
            console.log(routePoints);
            if(i >= 0 && i < routePoints.length - 4){
                dataSetString += '["' + routePoints[i] + '", "' + routePoints[i + 1] + '", "' + routePoints[i + 2] + '"],';
            }else if(i == routePoints.length - 3){
                dataSetString += '["' + routePoints[i] + '", "' + routePoints[i + 1] + '", "' + routePoints[i + 2] + '"]';
            }
        }
```

If I simply deleted the "undefined" and paste the code in, the datatabe populates fine, but I cannot see where the undefined is even coming from. Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why this was downvoted?

Comment: You have to post your `routePoints` array here. (I did not downvote).

Comment: Typo? Or are you missing closing quotes on the last item in each array?

Comment: that was a typeo when i copy and pasted it in. I attempted to shorten it....adding routePoints now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't compose a String like that.
It doesn't look like you need a string anyway but a 2D array.

```js
var data = ["41.8059016", "-77.0727825", "School Zone",
  "41.804526", "-77.075572", "Something",
  "41.804398", "-77.0743704", "Some Other Thing",
  "41.8073731", "-77.07304", "Pedestrian"
];

var dataString = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=3) dataString.push(data.slice(i, i + 3));

console.log(dataString);
// Should you actually need a string, you can use JSON.stringify()
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataString));
```

Comment: @MarcusHolden I'm creating an array of arrays. Printing that array to the console will print commas in between the array's elements.

Comment: This is perfect. I'm not sure what was screwing it up (still searching for the culprit), but it's working perfectly now. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @MarcusHolden You're welcome! If this is what you were looking for, I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the undefined comes from your initialization. I don't see the code here, but you probably have something like:

var dataSetString;

instead, you should always start an empty string as:

var dataSetString = "";

As to *why* this happens. All uninitialized variables default to `undefined`. When you use the `+=` operation, it will try to interpret what your are doing (if you have two numbers it will add them, two strings: concatenate). Undefined has no good `+=` operation, so it uses the second part of the operation the string you are passing in. So, it automatically converts the `undefined` to a string and concatenates the new string to it, ending up with `"undefined[blah,blah,blah"`

Comment: This is my assumption as well. I was about to answer the same.

Comment: This got it. such a dumb mistake..... I didn't realize you had to do that for strings. (i'm still fairly new at javascript)

Comment: No worries, happens to us all. Happy coding.